# Service fine as local system, but has faulting module as network service?

Tags: windows, service, com

I'm a little stumped as to why this windows service is not running when using the `Network Service` account (but does so on other machines using the same code), getting me these two subsequent errors in event viewer:

```
Application: MyApplication.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: exception code c0000005, exception address 06F3C67E
Stack:
```

and

```
Faulting application name: MyApplication.exe, Version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x87654321
Faulting module name: ReferencedComLib.dll, Version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x12345678
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000c67e
Faulting process ID: 0x148c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d4df2e591220f2
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApplication\MyApplication.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ReferencedComLib.dll
Report ID: 9d8df956-4b21-11e9-80c8-00155dc82141
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

This seems to indicate that the service is looking for ReferencedComLib.dll under C:\Windows\SYSTEM32...

But ReferencedComLib.dll is actually located under C:\Windows\SysWOW64 - it's a COM-library from third party (and their installer correctly installs it into SysWOW64)

Running under `Local System` however this error does not even show up and the service runs without problems - and this problem is currently only reproducable on one stage, on all others it is running fine with `Network Service`.

How could changing the service account running the service result in a faulting module?

Comment: The problem is not due to the fact ReferencedComLib is looked for. The report indicates that it's the faulting module => the cause of the problem. The fact you see System32 is normal (every process sees a "System32" that is redirected to the real system directory). Code in ReferencedComLib probably needs local admin rights because it accesses something it cannot when running under network service.

Comment: @SimonMourier yes I think that too, but why would it only fail under one user? Registration of dlls was always done by administrator and not any other account I just try to find out what could be different to the other stages :)

Comment: Local System is not one user, it's the one god of the machine. You should trace what ReferencedComLib does (for example with a tool such as Process Monitor from sysinternals) or ask its developer for help

Comment: @SimonMourier ty, this really helped ;) I'll write a more detailed answer later...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Simon Mourier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403671/simon-mourier) was right, the problem was internal to the third party dlls I am using and it was trying to access a directory that was under `C:\Users`....

Reinstalling under a different path that Network Service could access fixed the problem.